# Pod cannot import UIKit

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I follow the https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html to create pod module.
After created, when I try to import UIKit, it got cross out as shown below.

[image]

What do I need to do to get UIKit available on my pod module?

Comment: can you show a little more, what does your project navigator look, and where are you trying to import UIKit?

Comment: Did you open the `xcworkspace` file or the `xcproject` file? With pods, you have to use the `xcworkspace` file.

Comment: This should work just fine. What you're seeing sometimes happens in the autocompletion. What happens if you just type it out, do you get compilation errors?

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the feedback. Indeed I just need to ignore the strikeout and import the UIKit, and then I can use it. The strikeout confuses me at first. (do you know why it strikeout?)

Comment: Besides, what's the use of `s.ios.framework  = 'UIKit'` in the podspec file? With or without it, I can still import UIKit. (and both also show strikeout)

Comment: Xcode is a beast that is not able to be tamed. ESPECIALLY with how it handles all its linking stuff. It is not up to us to question its ways.